# Get file attributes by URL

Tags: java, file, dropbox

I've got a file at my dropbox storage. How can I get its attributes like creation time using URL? Is that even possible?
My effort:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException {
        URL url=new URL("http://www.dropbox.com/s/pumsh8ns1nvprb9/kazan.zip?dl=1");
        File file = new File(url.getPath());
        Path path = file.toPath();
        BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
        System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
        System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());

    }
```

Console says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
>   \s\pumsh8ns1nvprb9\kazan.zip

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood the File class. It must reference a file or directory.

Although you can create a new File object using an URI, the protocol (as the javadoc says http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.net.URI)) must be *file:*, not *http*, so I'm not sure you'll be able to read the properties of a file that way.

May be you should download the file to a temporary file (*File.createTempFile*, *deleteOnExit()*), then read the attributes.

Another solution is using the Dropbox API (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata).

Or its Java API (https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java): http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#getMetadata%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: File is big, so downloading is not the solution.

Comment: Use the Dropbox API to access the file metadata, answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache commons-io, just one line code:

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File)
```

Comment: The problem is that he doesn't want to download the file